# F# debugger hangs after hitting breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#, debugging

After hitting breakpoints (an apparently random number of times) and attempting to continue (F5) the debugger seems to hang. If I pause it, nothing happens. I have to stop it, and start over debugging. Anyone else encountered this? Any suggestions on how to fix or work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause of a debugger hang is an implicit function / property evaluation occurring which itself locks or goes into an infinite loop.  Try disabling implicit property and `.ToString` evaluation and see if it fixes the problem

- Tools -> Options -> Debugger
- Uncheck "Enable implicit property evaluation ..."

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I can't accept the answer until I ruminate on it for 5 more minutes (according to the wisdom of SO). We don't want to be too hasty accepting as reality what our eyes can see. :)